# number of total maximum values in a collection JAVA

Tags: java, numbers

### Can anybody help me with these easy method in Java? I can't find the right solution.

This is the method:
`Public static <E> int numberMaximus (Collection <E> collection, Comparator <? Super E> comparator)`

It receives a collection and a comparator and must return any values ​​in the collection that have the maximum value. According to the order of the comparator. In case comparator is **null** it is assumed that the elements of the collection implement the interface Comparable.

Here's an example to try the method, the next call should return **2** (the maximum is three, which is twice):
*NumberMaximus(Arrays.asList (1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 1, 2, 2), null)*

---

I think the code should be like...

```js
public static <E> int numberMaximus(Collection<E> collection, Comparator<? super E> comparator){
  int cont = 0;
  int max = 0;
  Iterator it = collection.iterator();
   if(comparator == null){ //Comparator is null
    while(it.hasNext()){
     if(it.next() > max){
      max = it.next();
      //Here something to know the number of values...
     }
    }
    
   }else{ //Comparator not null
    while(it.hasNext()){
     if(it.next().equals(comparator)){
      cont++;
     }
     
    }
   }
   
  return cont;
  
 }
```

Comment: Please provide the code you already came up with

Comment: What have you tried already? Have you read the docs for `Comparator`?

Comment: You might user Collections.max().

Comment: you could sort your List with `Collections.sort()`, then get the highest element and just count down how many elements share this value - if you find an element with a different value, you're done, since it's sorted

Comment: @Japu_D_Cret but I can't sort my "collection" element (How can I do it? `collection.sort()` isn't possible), but in case there's only valid when comparator ==null right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I have been able to come up with:

```
public static <E> int numberMaximus(Collection<E> coleccion, Comparator<? super E> comparador){
    E maximo;
    Comparator<? super E> comp = comparador;
    if (comp == null) {
        comp = (o1, o2) -> ((Comparable<E>)o1).compareTo(o2);
    }

    maximo = coleccion.stream().max(comp).orElse(null);
    if (maximo == null) {
        return 0;
    }
    return (int)coleccion.stream().filter(x -> x == maximo).count();
}
```

First, it decides what comparator to use. If the parameter is not null, use the parameter. If it is null, use `(o1, o2) -> ((Comparable<E>)o1).compareTo(o2)`, because you said to treat it as if it implements `Comparable<E>`.

Find out the max using the stream API's `max` method. If there isn't a max, return 0. If there is, remove everything that is not `maximo` and count how many are left.

Comment: I think your method is perfect. You're a _master of Java!_, but you use  streams and arrow functions that is really advanced programming in java for me. I know them but I don't know how to use it well yet. `stream()` is only for **Java 8**, right? I think that I understand your explanation, Thank so much for your time @Sweeper

Comment: @AAg If you think my answer answers your question, please consider accepting by clicking on that checkmark!

Comment: I prefer to wait, maybe someone posts another answer